# Не срабатывает кнопка backspace у калькулятора на js

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает кнопка backspace, должно удалять последний элемент у текущего инпут.

```
function back() {
   let valueInput = document.form.input_text.value;
   document.form.input_text.value = valueInput.substring(0,valueInput.length-1);
}
```

https://codepen.io/igor-solodownik/pen/VwpzjqE

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, что такое "текущего инпут".

```js
function back() {
  let valueInput = document.form.input_text.value;
  document.form.input_text.value = valueInput.substring(0, valueInput.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input name="input_text" value="1234567">
  <button type="button" onclick="back()">Click</button>
</form>
```

---

```
  ...
  <div class="item digit">1</div>
  <div class="item digit">2</div>
  <div class="item digit">3</div>
  <div class="item equally">=</div>
  <div class="item zero digit">0</div>
  <div class="item digit">.</div>


  if (this.classList.contains('digit'))
     insert(this.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Это vue js, а на нативном не работает( Если использовать данный код: function back() {
  let valueInput = document.form.input_text.value;
  document.form.input_text.value = valueInput.substring(0, valueInput.length - 1);   https://codepen.io/igor-solodownik/pen/VwpzjqE
}

Comment: @salco2012 Вы невнимательно прочитали мой ответ. `insert(this.innerHTML);` -  вот это что делает?