# Возникает ошибка в стрелочной функции js

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть функция, она работает корректно, но, стоит перевести ее в стрелочную, как выдает ошибку, не могу понять иза чего этот баг.

```js
function findVowels(str) {
   let test = str.match(/[aeiou]/g)
   return test ? test.length : 0;
}




console.log(findVowels('hello'));
console.log(findVowels('why'));
```

```js
function findVowels(str) => {
   let test = str.match(/[aeiou]/g)
   return test ? test.length : 0;
}




console.log(findVowels('hello'));
console.log(findVowels('why'));
```

Comment: Баг в том, что вы не знаете, как пишутся стрелочные функции

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const findVowels = (str) => {
   let test = str.match(/[aeiou]/g)
   return test ? test.length : 0;
}

console.log(findVowels('hello'));
console.log(findVowels('why'));
```

Comment: Спасибо) странно, почему в моем варианте она не работала? Ведь так тоже можно объявлять?

Comment: @salco2012 так нельзя объявлять